# OpenGL Model/Texture rendering using VAO/VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, vbo, vao

I am trying to render 3D models with textures using [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/). The conversion goes perfect, all textures positions and what not gets loaded. I have tested the texture images by drawing them to the screen in 2D. 
For some reason it does not render the textures to the model.
I am a beginner in OpenGL so forgive me if i dont explain it right.
The tutorial I have based the code on is from [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/), but i stripped a big part since I have my own camera/movement system.

The model renders like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sK9K.png

whilest the texture in use looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWGp7.jpg

The relevant rendering code is the following:

Generating textures from data file:

```
int Mesh::LoadGLTextures(const aiScene* scene){
  if (scene->HasTextures()) return -1; //yes this is correct
  /* getTexture Filenames and Numb of Textures */
  for (unsigned int m = 0; m<scene->mNumMaterials; m++){
    int texIndex = 0;

    aiReturn texFound;
    aiString path;  // filename

    while ((texFound = scene->mMaterials[m]->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, texIndex, &path)) == AI_SUCCESS){
        textureIdMap[path.data] = NULL; //fill map with textures, pointers still NULL yet
        texIndex++;
    }
  }

  int numTextures = textureIdMap.size();
  /* create and fill array with GL texture ids */
  GLuint* textureIds = new GLuint[numTextures];

  /* get iterator */
  std::map<std::string, GLuint>::iterator itr = textureIdMap.begin();

  std::string basepath = getBasePath(path);

  ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image;
  for (int i = 0; i<numTextures; i++){
    std::string filename = (*itr).first;  // get filename
    (*itr).second = textureIds[i];    // save texture id for filename in map
    itr++;                                // next texture

    std::string fileloc = basepath + filename;  /* Loading of image */
    image = al_load_bitmap(fileloc.c_str());

    if (image) /* If no error occured: */{
        GLuint texId = al_get_opengl_texture(image);

        //glGenTextures(numTextures, &textureIds[i]); /* Texture name generation */
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId); /* Binding of texture name */
        //redefine standard texture values
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); /* We will use linear
                                                                          interpolation for magnification filter */
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); /* We will use linear
                                                                          interpolation for minifying filter */
        textureIdMap[filename] = texId;
    } else {
        /* Error occured */
        std::cout << "Couldn't load Image: " << fileloc.c_str() << "\n";
    }
  }

  //Cleanup
  delete[] textureIds;

  //return success
  return true;
}
```

Generating VBO/VAO:

```
void Mesh::genVAOsAndUniformBuffer(const aiScene *sc) {
  struct MyMesh aMesh;
  struct MyMaterial aMat;
  GLuint buffer;

  // For each mesh
  for (unsigned int n = 0; n < sc->mNumMeshes; ++n){
    const aiMesh* mesh = sc->mMeshes[n];

    // create array with faces
    // have to convert from Assimp format to array
    unsigned int *faceArray;
    faceArray = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * mesh->mNumFaces * 3);
    unsigned int faceIndex = 0;

    for (unsigned int t = 0; t < mesh->mNumFaces; ++t) {
        const aiFace* face = &mesh->mFaces[t];

        memcpy(&faceArray[faceIndex], face->mIndices, 3 * sizeof(unsigned int));
        faceIndex += 3;
    }
    aMesh.numFaces = sc->mMeshes[n]->mNumFaces;

    // generate Vertex Array for mesh
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &(aMesh.vao));
    glBindVertexArray(aMesh.vao);

    // buffer for faces
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * mesh->mNumFaces * 3, faceArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // buffer for vertex positions
    if (mesh->HasPositions()) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * mesh->mNumVertices, mesh->mVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    // buffer for vertex normals
    if (mesh->HasNormals()) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * mesh->mNumVertices, mesh->mNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(normalLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    // buffer for vertex texture coordinates
    if (mesh->HasTextureCoords(0)) {
        float *texCoords = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 2 * mesh->mNumVertices);
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < mesh->mNumVertices; ++k) {
            texCoords[k * 2] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].x;
            texCoords[k * 2 + 1] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].y;
        }

        glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLoc);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 2 * mesh->mNumVertices, texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    }

    // unbind buffers
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // create material uniform buffer
    aiMaterial *mtl = sc->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

    aiString texPath;   //contains filename of texture
    if (AI_SUCCESS == mtl->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &texPath)){
        //bind texture
        unsigned int texId = textureIdMap[texPath.data];
        aMesh.texIndex = texId;
        aMat.texCount = 1;
    } else {
        aMat.texCount = 0;
    }

    float c[4];
    set_float4(c, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    aiColor4D diffuse;
    if (AI_SUCCESS == aiGetMaterialColor(mtl, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_DIFFUSE, &diffuse))
        color4_to_float4(&diffuse, c);
    memcpy(aMat.diffuse, c, sizeof(c));

    set_float4(c, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    aiColor4D ambient;
    if (AI_SUCCESS == aiGetMaterialColor(mtl, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_AMBIENT, &ambient))
        color4_to_float4(&ambient, c);
    memcpy(aMat.ambient, c, sizeof(c));

    set_float4(c, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    aiColor4D specular;
    if (AI_SUCCESS == aiGetMaterialColor(mtl, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_SPECULAR, &specular))
        color4_to_float4(&specular, c);
    memcpy(aMat.specular, c, sizeof(c));

    set_float4(c, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    aiColor4D emission;
    if (AI_SUCCESS == aiGetMaterialColor(mtl, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_EMISSIVE, &emission))
        color4_to_float4(&emission, c);
    memcpy(aMat.emissive, c, sizeof(c));

    float shininess = 0.0;
    unsigned int max;
    aiGetMaterialFloatArray(mtl, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, &shininess, &max);
    aMat.shininess = shininess;

    glGenBuffers(1, &(aMesh.uniformBlockIndex));
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, aMesh.uniformBlockIndex);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(aMat), (void *)(&aMat), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    myMeshes.push_back(aMesh);
  }
}
```

Rendering model:

```
void Mesh::recursive_render(const aiScene *sc, const aiNode* nd){
  // draw all meshes assigned to this node
  for (unsigned int n = 0; n < nd->mNumMeshes; ++n){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myMeshes[nd->mMeshes[n]].texIndex);

    // bind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(myMeshes[nd->mMeshes[n]].vao);

    // draw
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, myMeshes[nd->mMeshes[n]].numFaces * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
  }

  // draw all children
  for (unsigned int n = 0; n < nd->mNumChildren; ++n){
      recursive_render(sc, nd->mChildren[n]);
  }
}
```

Any other relevant code parts can be found in my open github project https://github.com/kwek20/StrategyGame/tree/master/Strategy

Mesh.cpp is relevant, as well as main.cpp and Camera.cpp.

As far as I understaind I followed the guidelines well, created a VAO, created VBOs, added data and enabled the proper vertex array attriute tot render the scene with.

I have checked all the data variables and everything is filled according to plan

Could anyone here spot the mistake I have made and or explain it?
Some links are typed weird because of the limit I have :(

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you posted your shaders also.
I can post some rendering code with textures if that helps you out:
Generating the texture for opengl and loading a grayscale (UC8) image with width and height into the GPU

```
void GLRenderer::getTexture(unsigned char * image, int width, int height)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &mTextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB8, width, height);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    if (aux::checkGlErrors(__LINE__, __FILE__))assert(false);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Loading the vertices from assimp onto the gpu

```
    //** buffer a obj file-style model, initialize the VAO
void GLRenderer::bufferModel(float* aVertexArray, int aNumberOfVertices, float* aNormalArray, int aNumberOfNormals, float* aUVList, int aNumberOfUVs, unsigned int* aIndexList, int aNumberOfIndices)
{
    //** just to be sure we are current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mWin);

    //** Buffer all data in VBOs
    glGenBuffers(1, &mVertex_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertex_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * aNumberOfVertices * 3, aVertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &mNormal_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mNormal_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * aNumberOfNormals * 3, aNormalArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &mUV_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mUV_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * aNumberOfUVs * 2, aUVList, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &mIndex_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndex_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * aNumberOfIndices, aIndexList, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (aux::checkGlErrors(__LINE__, __FILE__))assert(false);

    //** VAO tells our shaders how to match up data from buffer to shader input variables
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(mVertex_array_object);

    //** vertices first
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertex_buffer_object);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    //** normals next
    if (aNumberOfNormals > 0){
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mNormal_buffer_object);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    }
    //** UVs last
    if (aNumberOfUVs > 0){
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mUV_buffer_object);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    }
    //** indexing for reusing vertices in triangle-meshes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndex_buffer_object);


    //** check errors and store the number of vertices
    if (aux::checkGlErrors(__LINE__, __FILE__))assert(false);
    mNumVert = aNumberOfVertices;
    mNumNormals = aNumberOfNormals;
    mNumUVs = aNumberOfUVs;
    mNumIndices = aNumberOfIndices;

}
```

The code above is called like:

```
//read vertices from file
std::vector<float> vertex, normal, uv;
std::vector<unsigned int> index;
//assimp-wrapping function to load obj to vectors
aux::loadObjToVectors("Resources\\vertices\\model.obj", vertex, normal, index, uv);
mPtr->bufferModel(&vertex[0], static_cast<int>(vertex.size()) / 3, &normal[0], static_cast<int>(normal.size()) / 3, &uv[0], static_cast<int>(uv.size()) / 2, &index[0], static_cast<int>(index.size()));
```

Then comes the shader-part:
In the vertex shader you just hand-through the UV-coordinate layer

```
#version 400 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;

[... in main then ...]
UV = vertexUV;
```

While in the fragment shader you assign the value to the pixel:
    #version 400 core
    in vec2 UV;
    uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
    layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
    [... in main then ...]
    // you probably want to calculate lighting here then too, so its just the simplest way to get the texture inside
    outColor = vec4(texture2D(textureSampler, UV).rgb, cosAngle);
    //you can also check whether the UV coords are correctly bound by using:
    outColor = vec4(UV.x, UV.y,1,1);
    //and then checking the pixel-values in the resulting image (e.g. render it to a PBO and then download it onto the CPU for)

In the rendering loop also make sure that all the uniforms are correctly bound (especially texture related ones) and that the texture is active and bound

```
if (mTextureID != -1) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID); 
}

GLint textureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(mShaderProgram, "textureSampler");
glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
//**set the poligon mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
//**drawElements because of indexing
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mNumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I hope I could help you! 
Kind regards,
VdoP

Comment: Whoa man! You realise i posted this almost 3 years ago right?!
I never got past it though, time to dig up that old project again. Ill let you know how it goes :)